# How to ignore eslint rules in standard

Tags: javascript, standards, eslint, package.json, lint

I have `standardjs` installed and this is my configs in `package.json`

```
"standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ignore": [
      "dist/",
      "*env*"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off"
    }
  }
```

How do I ignore some of the eslint rules in this config file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already adding one ESLint rule to ignore ('eqeqeq'). You just need to add the rules you want to ignore in the "rules" object in your config file, with the value "off".

```
"rules": {
    "eqeqeq": "off",
    "no-console": "off"
}
```

See: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files

Answer (score 0):

Guys the answer is `standardx`a standard with custom tweaks.